# Cordova not working with threejs?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, three.js, cocoonjs

I have a game written with three.js in javascript, I am using Cordova to try to put it on the IOS and android store but Cordova doesn't seem to support webGL, and if i use a canvas renderer my game is really slow, I am thinking of trying cocoonJS.

So basically can i use three.js with Cordova and if not does cocoonJS support webGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well-known fact that Android's web view is not accelerated to the extent of iOS or even Windows Phone 8 (it's slowly catching up though). I'm not sure what's going on with three.js and Cordova, [*apparently they don't get along*](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/4053-cordova-and-threejs-wont-get-along/), but CocoonJS does support WebGL [in its latest incarnation](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/features/webgl/). Ludei even have a [demo app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ludei.demos.webgl). For more information, I suggest you check with Ludei support, as I'm certainly no expert.